# Regex: Match all permutations

Tags: regex

First of all, I am aware that this is a problem you wouldn't usually use regex for, I am just trying to find out whether this is even possible.

That being said, what I am trying to do is match ALL occurrences of any permutation of a string (for now, I don't care if overlapping occurences match or not); for example, if I have the string `abc`, I want to match all occurrences of `abc`, `acb`, `bac`, `bca`, `cab` and `cba`.

What I have until now is the following regex: `(?:([abc])(?!.{0,1}\1)){3}` (note: I know that I could use `+` instead of `{0,1}`, but that only works for strings with length 3). This kind of works, but if there are two permutations next to each other where a letter of the first one is too close to a letter of the second one (eg. `abc cba` → `c c`), the first permutation does not match. Is it possible to solve this using regex?

Comment: Replace `.` with `[abc]`. Or at least `\S` or  `[^ ]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good idea, but that still doesn't match eg. the `abc` in `abcccab`...

Comment: `([abc])(?!\1)([abc])(?!\1|\2)[abc]`? See https://regex101.com/r/D5OOcD/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is also an option I considered, but as soon as my pattern is longer than 3 characters (eg. `abcd`) I'd need to significantly change the regex; therefore, I was wondering if it is possible to get a regex where I really just have to plug in the pattern and its length and it just always works

Comment: No, it is not possible with common regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct Approach**

`[abc]{3}` would match too many results since it would also match `aab`.
In order to not double match `a` you would need to remove a from the group that follows leaving you with `a[bc]{2}`.

`a[bc]{2}` would match too many results since it would also match 'abb'.
In order to not double match `b` you would need to remove a from the group that follows leaving you with `ab[c]{1}` or `abc` for short.

`abc` would not match all combinations so you would need another group.

`(abc)|([abc]{3})` which would match too many combinations again.

This path leads you down the road of having all permutations listed explicitly in groups.

Can you create combinations so that you do not need to write out all combinations?

`(abc)|(acb)` could be writtean as `a((bc)|(cb))`.

`(bc)|(cb)` I can not shorten that any further.

**Match too many and remove unwanted**

Depending on the regex engine you may be able to express `AND` as a look ahead so that you can remove matches. THIS and not THAT consume THIS.

`(?=[abc]{3})(?=(?!a.a))[abc]{3}` would not match aca.

This problem is now simmilar to the one above where you need to remove all combinations that would violate your permutations. In this example that is any expression containing the same character mutltiple times.

'(.)\1+' this expression uses grouping references on its own matches the same character multiple times but requires knowing how many groups exist in the expression and is very brittle Adding groups kills the expression `((.)\1+)` no longer matches. Relative back references exist and require knowledge of your specific regex engine. `\k<-1>` may be what you could be looking for. I will assume .net since I happen to have a regex tester bookmarked for that.

The permutations that I want to exclude are: `nn.` `n.n` `.nn` `nnn`

So I create these patterns: `((?<1>.)\k<1>.)` `((?<2>.).\k<2>)` `(.(?<3>.)\k<3>)` `((?<4>.)\k<4>\k<4>)`

Putting it all together gives me this expression, note that I used relative back references as they are in .net - your milage may vary.

```
(?=[abc]{3})(?=(?!((?<1>.)\k<1>.)))(?=(?!((?<2>.).\k<2>)))(?=(?!(.(?<3>.)\k<3>)))(?=(?!((?<4>.)\k<4>\k<4>)))[abc]{3}
```

The answer is yes for a specific length.

[Here is some testing data.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%5babc%5d%7b3%7d%29%28%3f%3d%28%3f!%28%28%3f%3c1%3e.%29%5ck%3c1%3e.%29%29%29%28%3f%3d%28%3f!%28%28%3f%3c2%3e.%29.%5ck%3c2%3e%29%29%29%28%3f%3d%28%3f!%28.%28%3f%3c3%3e.%29%5ck%3c3%3e%29%29%29%28%3f%3d%28%3f!%28%28%3f%3c4%3e.%29%5ck%3c4%3e%5ck%3c4%3e%29%29%29%5babc%5d%7b3%7d&i=match+abc%2c+acb%2c+bac%2c+bca%2c+cab+and+cba+abc+cba%0d%0ano+match+aab%2c+aba%2c+baa%2c+aaa%0d%0astill+match+abc%2c+acb%2c+bac%2c+bca%2c+cab+and+cba+abc+cba)